# how can i view the first line of every file in my directory using python

Tags: python, file, loops, hex

I want to view the first line of each file in the directory in hex

I can use a loop to do it for all of the files but i need a way to view the first few bytes of a file

any ideas ?

Comment: is the file encoded as hex? or would like read convert content of the file to hex?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687516/how-to-read-binary-files-as-hex-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you : -

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('folderPath') if isfile(join('folderPath', f))]

for file in onlyfiles:
    with open(join('folderPath', file), 'r') as f:
        first_line = f.readline()
        print first_line
```

Answer (score 2):

pushpendra chauhan's answer is correct, but why should we use a for loop when it's not necessary (we are only looping once every time!)? (I cannot comment as I don't have sufficient reputation).

The other thing is, this will raise an IOError if you have any subdirectories in your path. So I added a line using os.path to see if the current 'file' is actually a file before attempting to open it.

```
import os

def read_first_line(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        print f.readline()

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if os.path.isfile(filename): read_first_line(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can read all files name in  the directory

```
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
```

and then you can read first line of each file

Here is the full code

```
import os

def readFile(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            print line
            break

for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    readFile(filename)
```