# Python convert exe file to bytes

Tags: python, byte, exe

I would like to convert exe file to bites in python and save the bites file.

The output file should look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9Axg.png)

Can anyone share a code that solves this issue? Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading binary file and looping over each byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035340/reading-binary-file-and-looping-over-each-byte)

Comment: Also [How to read binary files as hex in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34687516)